# Coercion in pairs

Tags: coq

Why do coercions not work inside pairs? In my project I have coercions from `Foo` to `Bar`, which works well if I have one `Foo` but want one `Bar`. But it does not work if I want a pair of `Bar`s, but have a pair of `Foo`s.

```
Inductive Foo := foo.
Inductive Bar := fromFoo of Foo.

Coercion fromFoo : Foo >-> Bar.

(* This works *)
Definition bar : Bar := foo.
(* This fails *)
Fail Definition bars : (Bar * Bar) := (foo,foo).
```

Why would Coq not insert the coercion here?